# What material should I use for a table tennis (ping-pong) table top

Tags: table

I would like to be able to convert our outside table into a table-tennis table for me and my children. The existing table is the right height (1" lower than standard table tennis table) and about the right size , just a bit shorter and thinner than the 9ft by 5ft size of a table tennis table, It is also slatted so not usable as a table tennis table on its own without a custom top.

So I simply want to create a top, I plan to create it as two separate parts split at the net of 4.5ft by 5ft so its fairly easy to remove. But what material should I use, and do I need to paint it to get a reasonable bounce. It doesn't need to be perfect but good enough so that  it seems like playing proper table tennis.

Its going to be outside, and although I can remove it Id rather be able to leave it on so some resilience to elements would be useful.

Im based in the UK

Comment: almost any top can work.  just be sure it is reasonbly smooth and not warped.  paint it with a water-proof paint unless you get a water-proof material.

Comment: In the 60s, plywood was pretty popular, and I've seen a fair number of those at summer camps. Put a lot of exterior grade paint on it.

Comment: How about (green) mdf ?